# How to rename a given 123.txt file in many subdirectories to add the folder name to that file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I need to find a given file, 123.txt, in all the subdirectories I have, and then add the particular sub-directory's name to that file. And even FORCE the bat file to overwrite existing file each time it's run.
For example:
    -folder
    --subfolder1
    ---123.txt
    --subfolder2
    ---123.txt
To sum up, a given file 123.txt is in many subdirectories.
I would want to have all 123.txt files RENAMED as NEW files (overwrite each time) with folder names added to them (separated by dash). So I need files like 
    --subfolder1
    ---subfolder1-123.txt
    --subfolder2
    ---subfolder2-123.txt
Please help. A batch file doing this please.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a homework assignment? Please tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Berend I am novice to all of this. And this is work. I have surfed 100 of pages from tens of Google searches but to no avail. But yes, it indeed looked easy enough to me, and I was sure that maximum two searches on Google would do the job. Please help if you can.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this: Loop recursively over all folders, check if a file called 123.txt exists, and if so, rename it. Note that `~n` returns the name part of the directory contained in the `%%d` variable.

Save the following to a file with a `.bat` extension and run it from the directory where your 123 files are located.

```sh
@echo off
for /r /d %%d in (*.*) do (    
    if exist "%%d\123.txt" ( 
        rename "%%d\123.txt" "%%~nd-123.txt"
    )
)
```

Or as a oneliner to be run from a command prompt directly (note the single `%` characters):

```sh
for /r /d %d in (*.*) do (if exist "%d\123.txt" rename "%d\123.txt" "%~nd-123.txt")
```

Help for most of the above can be read by typing `for /?` on a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you help a bit more with this. How could I keep the original 123.txt as 123.txt, and get a new file subfolder-123.txt ? Thanks a ton!

Comment: instead of `rename ...` use `mkdir "%%d-123.txt"`

Comment: mkdir didn't work. It says that 123.txt already exists.
I tried copy "%%d\123.txt" "%%~nd-123.txt"
it works but with a prob, it's creating the new file in the bat file location, not in the location of 123.txt file itself.

Comment: Yeah, `%%~nd-123.txt` is just a directory name without path (because of the `~n`). You should probably use `%%d`

Comment: Using %%d copies all 123.txt in different folders, but I needed folder name to differentiate by folder name.

Is it possible to create a *copy* of the file 123.txt in different subfolders by adding folder name to it?

Comment: The rename command doesn't overwrite, so is there an alternative? How could we use move command here so that it overwrites the file each time it is run? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell alternative:

```
gci C:\somewhere -r -filter 123.txt | % { rni $_.FullName -NewName ( "$( split-path (split-path $_.FullName -parent) -leaf )-123.txt" ) }
```

You can change the path in `gci` to your topmost directory and it will look for 123.txt in every subfolder there is and rename it with parentfolder-123.txt

run this from your PowerShell window

Comment: Didn't get any error when running it, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Krishna well it definetly works. is your file not named 123.txt? it will only grab files with that name and then rename them